# opencascade BRepOffsetAPI_Sewing is slow

Tags: opencascade

i have fairly large files with 3D scan points (200.000 ish) and try to make a TopoDS_Shape with BRepOffsetAPI_Sewing

```
gp_Pnt p1(0,0,100);
...
TopoDS_Edge e1 = BRepBuilderAPI_MakeEdge( p4, p1);
...
TopoDS_Wire w1 = BRepBuilderAPI_MakeWire(e1, e2, e3, e4);
...
TopoDS_Face f1 = BRepBuilderAPI_MakeFace(w1);
...
BRepOffsetAPI_Sewing sew(0.1);
sew.Add(f1);sew.Perform();TopoDS_Shape sewedShape = sew.SewedShape();
```

of corse with all the points in loops etc. above code is just a sample how I try to create things.

with 200.000 points it takes 20-30 second to produce the face.

my next approach was to save the produced shape after generated and load it later as a workaround.

```
BRepTools::Write(sewedShape, sFile);
```

but even that is slow.
I did similar things in Java3D and it was way faster. So I make something wrong.

only showing the points with

```
Handle_Graphic3d_ArrayOfPoints points3d = new Graphic3d_ArrayOfPoints(totPoints, true, false);
gp_Pnt pnt(x, y, z);
points3d->AddVertex(pnt, aColor); // adding 200.000 points
Handle(AIS_PointCloud) m_points = new AIS_PointCloud();
m_points->SetPoints(points3d);
m_occView->getContext()->Display(m_points, true);
```

is almost instant (less then a second)

my goal is to build 2 of those faces and find the intersection with OCBRepAlgoAPI_Section

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, your current approach is:

- Create a `TopoDS_Face` per quad in Point Cloud.

To avoid unnecessary overhead on sewing operation, you would need reconsidering your workflow and create shared shapes from the scratch. E.g., instead of creating `TopoDS_Vertex` for the same point in Point Cloud multiple times, you should create a single one and reuse it in construction of connected edges / quads; the same applies to `TopoDS_Edge` construction. What sewing operation does for you is finding and repairing shared information between geometrically connected faces - which is a plenty of work that could be entirely avoided.

But as you have been already pointed out (by trying to dump produced shape into a file), mapping tessellation to B-Rep is counter-efficient approach in general. Just take a look at all these `TopoDS_Vertex`, `TopoDS_Edge`, `TopoDS_Wire`, `TopoDS_Face` to figure out how much more data structures are needed in B-Rep for mapping a very single triangle or quad. This structure is heavy not only from memory utilization point of view, but also for algorithms you might want to do with it like Boolean operations.

Possible alternatives:

- Create a `Poly_Triangulation` from your point cloud and a single `TopoDS_Face` from it. You would be able to efficiently visualize it in 3D Viewer and perform some operations like computing surface area. Unfortunately, such geometry definition is not yet supported by all OCCT algorithms, so that you wouldn't be able performing Boolean operations.
- Create an approximated B-Spline surface from your Point Clouds. This could be done with help of [GeomPlate](https://dev.opencascade.org/doc/refman/html/class_geom_plate___build_plate_surface.html) or [SSP](https://www.opencascade.com/components/surface-from-scattered-points-component-sdk/) (Surface from Scattered Points) algorithms. Approximated surface would be a better fit to B-Rep geometry definition, but might loose some details of original surface and might be tricky to apply (you might need splitting a complex surface into several pieces).
- Use [OMF product](https://www.opencascade.com/components/mesh-framework-component/) (Mesh Framework) to perform Boolean operations on meshes. In case if Boolean operation on meshes is all you need, OMF could be helpful.